# Check if window is open, if not call another javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript to open another window and I want to check if that window is actually open, but then I want it to call a "pause()" function if the window is not open.  I have no clue how to do this even after 3 days of researching, can anybody guide me with this?

The javascript to open the window:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowSizeArray = ["width=300,height=300",
                                "width=200,height=400,scrollbars=yes"];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#newWindow').click();
            window.open($('#newWindow').attr('href'), 'window name', 'window settings')
            $('.newWindow').click(function (event) {

                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                var windowName = "popUp"; //$(this).attr("name");
                var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];

                window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });


    </script>
```

If that window is not open I want it to call a pause function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pause();"><img name="b1" src="system/modules/surf/stop.png" border="0" alt="Pause" title="Pause" style="position:absolute;top:28px;margin-left:5px"></a>
```

Comment: What to you expect your "pause" function to do?

Comment: My pause function is already set up in working, I just need something to call it if the window isn't open.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have two `window.open` calls.

Comment: I'm not sure, I followed a tutorial for it and it's been working fine for me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: If your design calls for one window opened you only need one `window.open` call (and the browser is likely to block extra window opens or calls not made during a user click in any case- it's possible your first call is ignored).

Comment: Well it's working how I want it to how it is, but some users can just close the window and still gain points for having it "open" when they actually closed it manually.  This is why I need to check that it is open and if it isn't to pause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `window.open()` returns a handle to your newly created window, which has a `closed` property. This property is true if the new window has been closed:

```
var popuphandle=window.open(...);
alert(popuphandle.closed);
```

If you need to monitor the status of the window continuously, use `window.setInterval()`:

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    if (popuphandle.closed) pause();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like it works but I'm really new to javascript, how would I add this in to my current code?

Answer (score 0):

you can, from your new window, tell the window.opener repeatedly that it is still opened by calling a function of the opener

`window.opener.callFunctionToTellIamOpened()`

to repeatedly call this function you can use setInterval http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp